# Are corporations "theys" or "its"?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

> Because Acme Inc. didn't deliver the item to Joe, he sued them.

> Because Acme Inc. didn't deliver the item to Joe, he sued it.

Which is correct? "Them" sounds right, but because a corporation is a separate legal entity, not merely a group of shareholders, "it" seems legally correct. (Perhaps this wasn't the best example because "he sued it" could mean he sued the item, but just think of a scenario where there is no ambiguity with either pronoun.)

Answer (score 2):

Technically, corporations have legal personhood so pronouns might not be incorrect for them. However you can avoid this by simply referring to one as "the company" or "the corporation":

> Because Acme Inc. didn't deliver the item to Joe, he sued the company.

From personal experience, many corporations use this in reference to themselves in their own boilerplate legal documents, e.g. "The company shall retain all rights to..."

Answer (score 2):

Corporations can be referred to by both "they" and "it". Depending on the situation one may fit better than the other. "It" is more impersonal, objective and passive, "they/them" more personal, subjective and active.

You could "love them", "hate them", "sue them". Or talk about how "it was founded", "it went bankrupt", "company B acquired it".

Just choose what sounds best to you, unless you have a style guide that requires you to use one or the other. (For example, reading a few articles on wikipedia about companies, they seem to try to conform to "it". Probably to make it sound more objective.)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, referring to a person or group of people as an "it" is considered rude in English.  Since the coorperation is a group of people, a singular or plural "them" should be used if referring to the group of people who can be sued.  It should only refer to a coorperation's products when the products are given brand-name recognition.

For example, if you drive a Ford F150 and refer to the vehicle as "the Ford", then you might say:

> I crashed in the Ford.  It's (The Ford's) airbags did not deploy.

However, when you sue, you do not sue objects but people.  You would sue companies which are legal entities.  Thus the following sentance.

> Because the Ford's (The vehicle's) airbags did not deploy, I sued Ford (the company) because they (The Ford Company) are responsible for it's (The Ford Truck's) poor manufacturing.

Notice that in the above sentance, it is clear that you are not suing an object with no agency of person, even though "Ford" refers to different nouns during the course the sentence.